A.I software or programs that compute modeling
Has anyone tried or use any A.I. powered software or app or add-in that when a dataset is given, it auto suggest a model, model function, some product for the given dataset?

https://sqlspreads.com/blog/excel-ai-tools/

Hey @AnshTandon, thx for the response, have you tried that app yourself? If so, what is your experience?
